# Draping surface on custom data rather than built in elevation data for 3d web scene in CityEngine webviewer app?

Tags: arcgis-online, 3d, arcgis-pro, cityengine, web-scene

When I publish a web scene from ArcGIS Pro to ArcGIS Online for use in a cityengine 3d web scene, all of my surfaces that I have custom elevations assigned to come out flat. As far as I can tell the only elevation data that the 3d webscene will read or apply, is the built in esri elevation data.   I'm trying to display subsurface geologic data.

Comment: The web scene you are publishing from Pro goes to the Scene Viewer not to City Engine. Currently publishing elevation image services from Pro to ArcGIS Online is not supported, are you using your own elevation services or local elevation data? The scene viewer does not support multiple elevation services that overlap one another. The Scene Viewer will try to merge the elevation layers together.  Support for multiple elevation services over the same area is planned for a future update.